# scanf is not waiting for input

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the bug here, but still don't get it.
I've been debugging and googling it and found some close topics, but there are only solutions which I don't need ATM, and I'm curious why this code is not working:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER 256

int main()
{   
    int missionCode;
    char *desc = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);

    do {
        printf("Please enter the mission code (or -1 for exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &missionCode);
        fflush(NULL);
        if (missionCode==-1)
            return 1;
    } while (missionCode>10);

    do {
        printf("Please enter a string:\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", desc); //it doesn't stop here!
        fflush(NULL);
        if (!strcmp("exit",desc))
            return 1;
    } while (strlen(desc)<20);

    printf("your string:\n%s", desc);
    return 0;
}
```

There's something wrong with the scanf\flushall in the second loop, but I don't find out what.
BTW, this is C ofcourse.

Comment: @MockingBird.. In your code, why are you flushing a `NULL` pointer i.e `fflush(NULL)`?

Comment: @Ganesh `fflush(NULL)` flushes all open output streams.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I agree with your comment. My doubt was more from flushing the output while we are only reading. I was trying to understand the motivation for flushing the output.

Comment: @Ganesh That is a good question.

Comment: Thanks guys but as Daniel Fischer said: changing scanf("%[^\n]s", desc); to scanf(" %[^\n]s", desc); fixes it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &missionCode);
```

leaves the newline in the buffer, so

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", desc);
```

immediately finds one and stops. You can add a space

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", desc);
```

to the format to skip initial whitespace.

Comment: First of all, thanks. It works now.
But I still have a question, what do you mean by
    scanf("%d", &missionCode);
leaves the newline in the buffer?
When I used fflush(NULL) it cleans the buffer, no?
Or do you mean that a clean buffer is similar to 'new line' in the buffer?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, `fflush(NULL)` only flushes output streams. `fflush`ing input streams is undefined behaviour, though some implementations promise that it does something sensible. You got a newline with the input, because (usually), the programme only receives any input after a newline has been typed [on Unixish systems, also a Ctrl+D which is not at the beginning of the line sends the input to the programme]. That newline is not consumed by the `scanf("%d",&missionCode);`, it remains in the input buffer. You could also empty the input buffer with (repeated) `getchar()` until the newline is found.