# Why does the printf statement execute infinitely?

Tags: c, infinite-loop

Header file used in program.

```
#ifndef choice_h
#define choice_h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int choice_list(){
int option;

puts("DATA CONFIRMATION AND UPDATE PROGRAM\n\n");
puts("1. Display data set now.\n");
puts("2. Delete an entry from the data set.\n");
puts("3. Add an entry to the end of the data set.\n");
puts("4. Change an existing entry.\n");
puts("5. Quit this program.\n");
puts("Enter choice [ 1-5, 0 = change data set]:");
scanf("%d", &option);

//this while loop tests against numbers [0-5] the choice called "option" that 
//was input by the user. Option needs to be in the range of [0-5] 
//in order for the user to select from the program menu.
while (!(0 == option || 1 == option || 2 == option || 3 == option || 4 == option || 5 == option))
{
    printf("\nInvalid Entry, please enter [0-5]: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
}

 //this if statement is an echo print to check the selected option
if (0 == option || 1 == option || 2 == option || 3 == option || 4 == option || 5 == option) {

    printf("you selected option: [%d]\n", option);
}

return option; //returns to calling function
}


 #endif /* choice_h */
```

===================================================

main program: This is not my entire program. I only posted up until where the error happened.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "../include/myheader.h"
 #include "../include/lab7_arrays.h"
 #include "../include/choice_list.h"

 int option_0(int ptr[]);
 int option_1(int ptr[]);
 int option_2(int ptr[]);
 int option_3(int ptr[]);
 int option_4(int ptr[]);

 main(){

 int data_1[MAX_VALUES] = {4, 7, 6, 32, 5};
 int data_2[MAX_VALUES] = {98, 47, 26, 99, 187};

    int option, choice;

    my_identity();
    print_arrays();
    puts("\nWhich set do you want to update [1 or 2]: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

//  this while loop checks and prompts the user to input an accepted value (1 or 2)
    while (!(1 == choice || 2 == choice))
    {
printf("\nInvalid Entry, please enter 1 or 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    }

if (1 == choice || 2 == choice)
    printf("\nDisplaying options for data set %d...\n\n", choice);

 //function defined in header file   
 option = choice_list();
    printf("option = %d choice = %d", option, choice);
```

/***** INFINITE LOOP STARTS HERE: just keeps printing out option and choice until I force exit the program *******/

```
    while (choice == 1||choice == 2)
    {
            if(choice == 1)
            { int *ptr = data_1;
              printf("choice: %d option: %d", choice, option);
                    switch(option)
                    {   case 0: option_0(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 1: option_1(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 2: option_2(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 3: option_3(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 4: option_4(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 5: break;
                           default: printf("Invalid input");
                    }
            }
            else
            { int *ptr = data_2;
                    switch(option)
                    {   case 0: option_0(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 1: option_1(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 2: option_2(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 3: option_3(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 4: option_4(ptr);
                                    break;
                            case 5: break;
                           default: printf("Invalid input");
                    }
            }
    }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }

 /*I have not yet written the code for these functions since I am still 
   working on the main part right now. The only one I defined is option 3 
   which adds an element to the end of the array the user decided to select.*/

 int option_0(int ptr[])
{
    return(0);
}

 int option_1(int ptr[])
{
    return(0);
}

 int option_2(int ptr[])
{
    return(0);
}

//add element to the end of array
int option_3(int ptr[])
{
    int i, value;
    int num_elements = sizeof(ptr)/sizeof(ptr[0]);
    /*printf("num_elements = %d", num_elements);

    printf("Enter number to add: ")
    scanf("%d", &value);

    ptr[num_elements] = value;
    */
    for (i = 0; i > num_elements; i++)
    {
            printf(" %d ",ptr[i]);
    }
 return 1;
 }

  int option_4(int ptr[])
 {
    int i = 0;
    return i;
 }
```

When compile and run:

```
 Program written by: KELSEY WILLIAMS 

 Program compiled on May  1 2018 at 04:54:01.

 Here is what data set 1 looks like now:


 [1]    [2]    [3]    [4]    [5]  

  4      7      6      32      5   

 Here is what data set 2 looks like now:


 [1]    [2]    [3]    [4]    [5]  

  98     47     26     99     187   
 Which set do you want to update [1 or 2]: 
 1

 Displaying options for data set 1...

 DATA CONFIRMATION AND UPDATE PROGRAM


 1. Display data set now.

 2. Delete an entry from the data set.

 3. Add an entry to the end of the data set.

 4. Change an existing entry.

 5. Quit this program.

 Enter choice [ 1-5, 0 = change data set]:
 3
 you selected option: [3]

 option = 3choice = 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 
 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 
 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 
 3choice: 1 and on and on and on....=(
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You should probably check the result of the `scanf` call. If it fails after the first time, `choice` keeps the value it had from the last success. That would explain an infinite loop. `scanf` returns the number of arguments it was able to write, just check the result is 1 and exit if it is 0.

Comment: a bad idea to include function definitions in header files but that is another issue, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823502/scanf-is-not-waiting-for-input

Comment: Where does the "choice: 1 option: 3" text get printed? You do not show it in the code you posted. You show where "option = 3 choice = 1" gets printed, which is different.

Comment: You need to show a [MCVE] as well as the exact input you provide to the program.

Comment: Consider what happens if `scanf("%d", &some_variable);` encounters non-numeric input.  What do you expect happens?

Comment: @IanAbbott thank you that was a copy and paste error

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever change the option, or break out of that `while` loop? So you say `choice` is 1. it will enter that `if` statement, go through the `switch` statement and then loop back to `while` loop. Why don't you add more debug `printf` to see where it goes inside the `switch`

Comment: For example 4 of your 5 `option()` functions simply return immediately so you'd have no idea if it wasn't going to the one you were expecting..

Comment: The very next line after "infinite loop starts here" is `while (choice == 1||choice == 2)`   , and inside that `while` you never exit the loop , nor modify `choice`. Why did you expect the loop to exit?

Comment: @M.M thanks, I didn't even realize I had that printf there again.

Comment: So what do you want the program to do after it has called one of the `option_N` functions? Because at the moment it calls them in an infinite loop `while (choice == 1 || choice == 2)`.

Comment: @IanAbbott eventually each option_N will make changes to the indicated array based on user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to re-create the error, I tried your code snippet on my IDE with `Main()` calling `choice_list()` which executed fine.

I also tried de-bugging with a break point and it did not get into a loop

[image]

Therefore, I reckon its the remaining section of the code snippet, which has not been updated in your question, is causing the infinite loop.

Besides, if you pay close attention to formatting of the message within the infinite loop you will notice that it is a different section of the code causing the loop.

```
choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 3choice: 1 option: 3
```

**P.S**: Although this may not be a definitive solution but hope this would point you in the right direction.
I can try and assist better if you post the relevant sections of the code snippet

Comment: @Kelsey, were you able to find out the reason for the infinite loop ?

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that I had put another printf statement in the while loop beneath the original code I had posted. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I ended up using a for loop instead

Comment: Glad the suggestion was helpful, it would be great if you could mark as answer if you think it was upto to the mark ! Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

**The culprit here is scanf( ) function**
scanf( ) somewhere in your program is getting some input other than numbers(decimal degits), like characters, symbols or escape sequence, that is the reason for infinity loop.

**Solution**
clear scanf( ) input buffer before getting input, use below code snippet in loop before scanf( ) funtion call in your choice_list( ) subroutine as well as in main( ) function.

```
[1]/* clears the input buffer */
while ((getchar()) != '\n');
```

like in choice_list( ) subroutine

```
...
...
while (!(0 == option || 1 == option || 2 == option || 3 == option || 4 == option || 5 == option))
{
    printf("\nInvalid Entry, please enter [0-5]: ");
   /* clears the input buffer */
    while ((getchar()) != '\n');  
    scanf("%d", &option);
}
...
...
```

**similarly, where you have used scanf( ) within loop, first clear the input buffer using code above[1] before calling scanf() function.**
Refer scanf() man page for more details.

Comment: Note that `while ((getchar()) != '\n');` is an infinite loop on end-of-file or input error.